# How many CCA is too little and indicates the battery needs replacing

Tags: battery, replace, parts-replacement

My mechanic said they tested my battery and saw it has 366 CCA.  The label on the battery says it has 500 CCA.  The battery is about 4 years old and the warranty is 42 months so it's outside of warranty right now.

In any case, my car is still starting fine (for now) so I'm wondering if I should change my battery or I can still safely use it for now?  What amount of CCA or what percentage of CCA should I replace the battery?  I also am aware that winter is around the corner so I probably will replace it before it gets too cold and I get stranded.

EDIT:
I drive a Honda CRV 2016.  I can't seem to find online how many CCA I need and the manual doesn't specify, although apparently 366 is enough for now :D

Comment: Some people say replace when it falls below 50%, others 25%. It also depends on your recovery options if you break down and how remote your driving takes you. But it's *likely* that you are OK to wait until winter sets in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one piece of information that you left out of your question is *How many CCA does your car require?* More cylinders and a higher-compression engine requires more amps to start. Your car manual may say.

There's no hard and fast rule for when to replace a battery due to reduced CCA. It's a judgment call. If this is not a good time to replace the battery, I can't fault you for squeaking another couple of months out of it. Just be aware that the battery is already at end of life and you're leaving yourself little wiggle room for something to go wrong.

Along with diminished CCA, your so-called "reserve capacity", or how long the car will run on battery if the alternator fails, is also diminished. Reserve capacity also has a bearing on how long you can accidentally leave your lights or accessories on without draining the battery so low that it won't start.

If you live in or park in a high crime area or drive long distances at night and could be in danger if you get stranded, it's time to replace the battery now. Otherwise, if you want to wait till the frost is on the pumpkin and you're sure you won't forget, feel free to wait, knowing the risk.

P.S. - Congratulations on finding a mechanic who goes the extra mile and actually tests your battery. They are a rare breed.